# Create a Highcharts Pie Chart Legend Inside a Table

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

Is there a way to create a Highcharts legend inside of a table? I want to be able to style the background of the legend for my Highcharts pie with alternating background colors for each element and custom borders.

I've formatted my legend like so, but cannot figure out how to embed it inside a table that I can then format.

```
legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
        borderWidth: 0,
        useHTML: true,
        itemMarginBottom: 10,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return '<div style="width:200px"><span style="float:left">' + this.name + '</span><span style="float:right">' + this.percentage.toFixed(0) + '%</span><span style="float:right; margin-right:15%">$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '</span></div>';
        }

    },
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/135/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put that legend in separate table, somewhere on a page - it's not supported.

If you want to just generate standard legend as is, but just use table instead of spans:

- instead of `return <div style="width:200px"> ... </div>` use `return <table> ... </table>`
- set useHTML: true

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to put each element into its own separate table row so that it can be styled separately? I'd like to be able to use alternating background colors for each element of the legend.

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding - unfortunately legend doesn't have one formatter for all labels, but formatter for each label, so returning one table, where each item is a row won't be possible right now.

Comment: And here is simple workaround using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/136/ (changed only font color, do the same for anything else).