# Alignment of Legend items content in Table structure in Highchart

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, highcharts

I am using Highcharts 4.2.4 in my application. I need to show Legend items in table aligned format so what I did is used legend properties like below:

```
legend: {                
                itemWidth: some fixed width
            }
```

This shows the legends much aligned in column structure way, but my legend items contains two fields one is Name and other is value so I need to split these two in again a column structure i.e. all legend items should show up two column one for Name and other for Value. Below is the reference Image, I expect the highlighted values(in yellow) to be in second red column that contents "Empty" in third row

[image]

I didn't find anything in Highchart to split up Legend content and have separate item widths for each content, is it possible with highchart?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238706/create-a-highcharts-pie-chart-legend-inside-a-table   might help

Comment: Additionally, You can add your values to another column using chart.renderer.label http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label